# Android layout design: image above form above button. When the keyboard appears my layout is screwed

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

In my application I want to have a layout like this:

[image: First layout]

I did it with a Relative Layout holding an ImageView, TableLayout and a Button. The problem is that when I open the keyboard to modify a EditText the keyboard is on top of the EditText, so the user can't see what he is writing. I want the layout to be like this when the keyboard is shown:

[image: Layout 2]

The user should be able to scroll up the view to see the whole image while the keyboard is shown, even if he doesn't see the EditText then, because he wants to copy some data of the image into the EditTexts. I tried to do it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonEditStop"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stopImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/entry_img"
            android:onClick="ImageClick" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/formLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/stopImg"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

           ...

        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/buttonEditStop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/edit_stop"
    android:onClick="EditButtonClicked"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
```

Using this code my whole layout is screwed. I see the form on top of the image, followed by a ImageButton with the image that should be seen in the imageView.

Anyone knows how I can get a layout like the one I want?

Thanks!

Comment: have you got overlapping appears in the time of key board?

Comment: Thanks to your comment I discovered android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". I used it in my manifest and, although I can't see the whole image when the keyboard is open, now I can see the EditText, and that's enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the EditText to be overlapped I had to use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in my manifest.